# Nop Commerce Custom View Engine for IComponents View Does'nt work in nopcommerce 4.0

Tags: asp.net-core, overriding, nopcommerce, nopcommerce-4.0

I have the following code in a custom plugin in NopCommerce v4.0

I am trying to Override the page of default ordertotal of IComponent  in nopcommerce and try to overrride from my Plugin with given Code

ViewLocationExpander.cs

```cs
public class BundledDiscountsViewEngine : IViewLocationExpander  
{
    public void PopulateValues(ViewLocationExpanderContext context)
    {
        //nothing to do here.

    }
    public IEnumerable<string> ExpandViewLocations(ViewLocationExpanderContext context, IEnumerable<string> viewLocations)
    {

        if (context.AreaName == null && context.ViewName == "Components/OrderTotals/Default")
        {
            viewLocations = new string[] { $"/Plugins/Demo/Views/Components/OrderTotals/{{0}}.cshtml"
            }.Concat(viewLocations);
        }

        return viewLocations;
    }
}
```

Nopstartup.cs

```cs
public class NopStartup : INopStartup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services, IConfigurationRoot configuration)
    {
        services.Configure<RazorViewEngineOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.ViewLocationExpanders.Add(new ViewLocationExpander());
        });
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder application)
    {
    }

    public int Order
    {
        get { return 1001; } //add after nopcommerce is done
    }
}
```

It calling is come  in ExpandViewLocations.cs file and also the path is OK but it redirect the default page of nopcommerce in Views/shared/component/OrderTotals/Default.cshtml

i have tried many different thing but didn't get any solution 
if any one have idea please reply

Thank you 
Ilyas Patel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I face the same issue , In nop 4.0 there is they take default view path you have to just declare like this

```
  viewLocations = new string[] { $"/Plugins/Demo/Views/{{0}}.cshtml"
                }.Concat(viewLocations);
```

It can helpful

Comment: https://weblogs.asp.net/imranbaloch/view-location-expander-aspnet5-mvc6

yes i have check using this link and the above solution is helpful 

thnx @sagar kaysath